# Return the table data using stored procedure in acumatica

Tags: acumatica

Unable to get the complete table data from stored procedure. For easy understanding, I have provided a simple stored procedure. Internally, we have different logic and different stored procedure that will return a table.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetResultWeeklyUnitSold]
    @fromDate VARCHAR(10),
    @toDate VARCHAR(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM SOOrder 
    WHERE OrderDate BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
End 

var pars = new List<PXSPParameter>();
PXSPParameter fromDate = new PXSPInParameter("@fromDate", 
PXDbType.VarChar, Filters.Current.StartDate);
PXSPParameter toDate = new PXSPInParameter("@toDate", PXDbType.VarChar, 
Filters.Current.EndDate);
pars.Add(fromDate);
pars.Add(toDate);

var results = PXDatabase.Execute("SP_WeeklyUnitSold",  pars.ToArray());
```

To get the result table from stored procedure.

Comment: ***WHY*** are you using `varchar(10)` datatype for your ***dates*** ?!!!?? Use `DATE` or `DATETIME` or something like that - **always** the **most appropriate** datatype, not just string for everything ......

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I advise you to reconsider use of stored procedure with Acumatica product. They are proscribed because they can break per company data isolation. There is no official support for them. More on this: https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/09/using-stored-procedures-in-acumatica.html

Comment: I would agree with all of the above - mostly avoiding any use of stored procedures and there is no passing of company ID so this call would run for all companies

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way of direct getting information from stored procedure of the whole table. 
The only working way I found, was serializing output into xml at stored procedure level, and then deserializing it in Acumatica.

But for case that you've described I can't understand, why not to use ordinary PXSelect? It will be much simpler and I'm sure much more efficient.